# Jordan-Hölder factors of a finite length module

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Suppose one has a local ring $(A,\mathfrak{m})$ and a finite length $A$-module $M$ with $\operatorname{supp}(M) = \{\mathfrak{m}\}$. Does $M$ have a composition series consisting only of $A/\mathfrak{m}$'s?

Comment: Does it follow from Eisenbud, Commutative Algebra, Theorem 2.13?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is true:

a) Since $M$ has finite length, it has by definition a composition series.
This means that  there exists a non-refinable filtration $M_0=M \supsetneq M_1 \supsetneq...\supsetneq M_n=0$ , in other words a filtration where each $M_i/M_{i+1}$ is a simple $A$-module.

b) Now, a simple $A$-module $S$ is isomorphic to $A/{\mathfrak m}$ with 
${\mathfrak m}\subset A$ maximal.
 Indeed choose a non-zero element $s\in S$ (the zero module is not  regarded as  simple!) and consider the morphism $f:A\to S: a\mapsto as$. Its image is non-zero [because $f(1)=s\neq0$] hence it is $S$ since, by  simplicity, $S$ is the only non-zero submodule of $S$ . So $f$ is surjective and $S\simeq A/Ker(f)$. But $A/Ker(f)$ can only be simple if $Ker(f)$ is a maximal ideal, so that $Ker(f)$ is a maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ and, as announced, $S\simeq A/\mathfrak m$

c) Since your  ring is local, $\mathfrak m$ is its only maximal ideal, and your question has an affirmative answer: $M$ has a composition series with quotients isomorphic to  $A/\mathfrak m$. As Pierre-Yves very judiciously remarks, you don't need the hypothesis that the support of $M$ is $\lbrace\mathfrak m \rbrace$.

**Acknowledgment**
My former proof was much more complicated and needed $A$ noetherian. Any  merit that the above proof might have should go to QiL and Pierre-Yves Gaillard (see their comments below).

Comment: Dear Georges: Which definition  of "finite length module" are you using?

Comment: Dear @Pierre-Yves, in order not to clutter the comments, I'll add a section to my answer giving two equivalent definitions of "finite length".

Comment: Dear Georges, isn't it simply the fact that the only simple module $M$ over a local ring $A$ is its residue field ? Such module is automatically generated by a single element because of the simplicity. By Nakayam (the noetherian hypothesis is not needed because $M$ is finitely generated), $\mathfrak m M \neq M$, hence $\mathfrak m M=0$ and $M$ is a vector space over $k$, generated by one element, so $M\simeq k$.

Comment: Dear Georges: Thanks for your edit, but it seems to me, from what you wrote, that the Jordan-Hölder factors of any finite length module, over any (commutative) ring, consists of modules of the form $A/\mathfrak m$, with $\mathfrak m$ maximal. So I don't understand why user5262 makes this support assumption, and why you make this noetherianity assumption... Sorry to bother you, but I'm really confused... [Dear @QiL: I hadn't read your comment while writing mine. It seems to me there are some similarities between our reactions.]

Comment: Dear@QiL, dear @Pierre-Yves, you are both right: noetherianity of $A$ is superfluous and my proof is much too complicated. I'll modify it and, of course, acknowledge your essential contributions. (I wish you had answered yourselves and saved me from embarrassment !)

Comment: Dear Georges: Thanks! By the way, localness and commutativity are also superfluous. Actually, you don't even have to know that the Jordan-Hölder factors are independent of the composition series. You just need to observe that, by their very definition, they are simple, *i.e.* of the form $A/I$, where $I$ is a maximal left ideal.